# Symfony login unable to find controller for path login_check despite being behind firewall

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am having this rather common problem of Symfony login failing with this error message:

`Unable to find the controller for path "/auth/login_check".`

The common answer to this problem is that the `login_check` route isn't behind the firewall, but in my case it is! Here are my config files:

**app/config/security.yml**

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:    ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security:   false

    auth_area:
        pattern:    ^/auth/(login|login_check)
        anonymous:  ~

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: /auth/login
            check_path: /auth/login_check
        logout:
            path:   /auth/logout
            target: /
```

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
login:
    pattern: /auth/login
    defaults: { _controller: AuthBundle:Default:login }

login_check:
    pattern: /auth/login_check

logout:
    pattern: /auth/logout
```

**AuthBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php**

```
public function loginAction()
{
  $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), new User());

  return $this->render('AuthBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('login_check'),
  ));
}
```

**AuthBundle/Form/Type/UserType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'Login:'));
  $builder->add('password', 'password', array('label' => 'Password:'));
}
```

**AuthBundle/Resources/views/Default/login.html.twig**

```
...
<form action="{{ action }}" method="POST">
  {{ form_widget(form) }}
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
...
```

My form is created with the route `login_check` as target (`/auth/login_check` URL).

The `secured_area` firewall is supposed to match all URLs, so `/auth/login_check` should be in it. Yet, I keep getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login_check url must behind the **same firewall** as the using firewall. use ACLs instead.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:    ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security:   false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: /auth/login
            check_path: /auth/login_check
        logout:
            path:   /auth/logout
            target: /
        anonymous:  ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/auth/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Doesn't this allow anonymous access to the whole website? By adding `anonymous: ~` in the `secured_area` firewall

Comment: No, as the last rule under `access_control` forces every access to every other location to have the `ROLE_USER` role, which only authenticated users can have.

Answer (score 0):

app/config/security.yml

```
secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/
    form_login:
        login_path: login  #this is routing name
        check_path: login_check  #this is routing name
    logout:
        path:   logout #this is routing name
        target: /
```

**Edit**

**[1]** you can try delete this:

```
auth_area:
    pattern:    ^/auth/(login|login_check)
    anonymous:  ~
```

**[2]** your path better that:

```
 <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="POST">
```

**Edit**

It is example for login

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /top
        logout:
            path:   /user_logout
            target: /
```

Comment: can you list you loginAction??

Comment: Removing `auth_area` causes a redirection loop as it makes authentication mandatory to access `/auth/login`, thus redirecting to the same URL. Thanks for the tip for the form action (although not solving the problem either).

Comment: It is my test example , hope it can help you

Comment: Not working either... Plus I don't want to allow any anonymous access to the site.

Comment: I do not know how about your firewalls is working ,you can try to set  firewall "dev"  'security: true' to test that the firewall is working .  if you also can see the tool bar , your firewall is not working

Answer (score 0):

**routing.yml**

```
login_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeUserBundle:Default:loginCheck }
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
public function loginCheckAction()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));
}
```